# Functional urban areas in the UK

Tags: geospatial, uk, city

I want to perform an analysis on **urban areas** **in the UK**. As, indeed, urban areas can be defined in multiple ways, I would like to rely on some well-accepted definitions and polygons.

I found this [EU project](http://database.espon.eu/db2/home) that has nice data about functional urban areas in the Union, but the source data is rather old (2000).

Then I found [UK city regions](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/articles/populationdynamicsofukcityregionssincemid2011/2016-10-11), one of the many admin units in the UK, but I can't find shapefiles for them (and they look very large).

Moreover, I would like to find a **point dataset with cities and towns** (a gazetteer) in the UK, with population information in order to use them as labels dynamically (e.g., show cities > 1M, etc.). The OS Open Names product is way too detailed, and does not seem to contain a handy categorisation between small and large centres.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an existing area definition you might want to have a look at European statistic [NUTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature_of_Territorial_Units_for_Statistics) regions.

There are different levels of granularity, as can be seen in this maps from eurostat:

- [NUTS maps UK](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/345175/7451602/nuts-map-UK.pdf)
- Eurostat NUTS [maps overview](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/nuts-maps-.pdf-)

Google also reveals a few random sources for the respective shapefiles (not reviewed in detail):

- http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts
- https://datahub.io/core/geo-nuts-administrative-boundaries
- https://data.gov.uk/dataset/nomenclature-of-units-for-territorial-statistics-nuts-level-2/resource/d83db713-f8ec-4c91-a53c-18e82bda7ae9